# React Typescript with C#/PostgreSQL Backend: Can't Render Fetched Data

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net, typescript, postgresql

I'm at my wits end with this problem, I'm fetching data from a PostgreSQL database with dummy data, getting and seeing the data when fetched, but it will not render in React no matter what I do.

Here's what I've been trying:

UserList component:

```
import {useEffect, useState} from 'react';

interface User {
    userId: number;
    userName: string;
    email: string;
}

function UserList() {
    const [users, setUsers] = useState<User[]>([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        getUsers()
            .then((resp) => {
                console.log('resp', resp);
                return resp.json();
            })
            .then((res) => {
                console.log('res', res);
                setUsers(res.data);
            });
    }, []);

    if (users !== undefined) {
        return (
            <div>
                {users.map((user) => (
                    <div key={user.userId}>
                        <h2>{user.userName}</h2>
                        <p>{user.email}</p>
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

async function getUsers(): Promise<Response> {
    return await fetch('user');
}

export default UserList;
```

App component:

```
import './App.css';
import UserList from "./UserList.tsx";


function App() {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1 id="tableLabel">User List</h1>
            <p>This component demonstrates fetching data from the server.</p>
            <UserList />
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Main:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import App from './App.tsx'
import './index.css'

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')!).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
)
```

Here are some **screenshots** of the console and network portions in the browser I'm using:
[Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q1C9V.png)
[Network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfcjI.png)

I genuinely have no idea why it isn't working. I've tried *so* much to get it to work.

I'm using Entity Framework in C#, if that matters. I'm pretty sure that isn't the problem though...
Let me know if you need additional information... I'm a bit desperate.

I've read other posts on similar issues, but their solutions did not help at all... I still can't get anything to render.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

interface User {
    userId: number;
    userName: string;
    email: string;
}

function UserList() {
    const [users, setUsers] = useState<User[]>([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        getUsers()
            .then((resp) => resp.json()) // Parse the JSON response
            .then((users) => {
                setUsers(users); // Assuming the JSON response is an array of users
            })
            .catch((error) => console.error('Failed to fetch users:', error)); // Handling possible errors
    }, []); // Empty dependencies array means this effect runs once on mount

    return (
        <div>
            {users.map((user) => (
                <div key={user.userId}>
                    <h2>{user.userName}</h2>
                    <p>{user.email}</p>
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
}

async function getUsers(): Promise<Response> {
    return await fetch('user'); // Ensure this URL is correct for your API
}

export default UserList;
```

Comment: Yes, this is correct! I actually arrived at this solution myself, baffled by how simple of a solution it was... extremely painful for me. All you had to change was `setUsers(res.data)` to `setUsers(res)`! This means I basically had the answer all of yesterday as well... Thank you very much anyways!